# View dependencies of a ballerina project

Tags: wso2, ballerina

I have a complex project that uses multiple dependencies. I need to get an idea of what versions of each dependency is used when my project is compiled. Does ballerina provide a way to view all dependencies of a project?

I tried creating a dependency graph manually, but it is too complicated since I need to find out the transitive dependencies of each direct dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bal graph CLI command](https://ballerina.io/learn/cli-documentation/cli-commands/) to get the dependency graph of your project.
You have to `bal graph` within the root directory of the project. You can use a DOT graph visualization tool to get a graphical representation of the graph command output.

The `bal graph` output would be similar to the below example.

```
digraph "samejs/app:0.1.0" {
    "samejs/app:0.1.0" -> "ballerina/http:1.3.1"
    "samejs/app:0.1.0" -> "samjs/foo:1.2.1"
    "samejs/app:0.1.0" -> "samtest/io:1.5.1"
    "ballerina/http:1.3.1" -> "ballerina/cache:1.2.1"
    "ballerina/http:1.3.1" -> "ballerina/io:1.0.2"
    "samjs/foo:1.2.1" -> "samjs/bar:1.3.4"
    "samjs/foo:1.2.1" -> "samjs/bazz:1.4.4"
    "samtest/io:1.5.1" -> "ballerina/http:1.3.1"
    "samtest/io:1.5.1" -> "samjs/c:0.4.6"
    "samtest/io:1.5.1" -> "samjs/q:1.4.4"
    "samjs/b:1.3.4" -> "samjs/c:0.4.6"
    "samjs/bar:1.3.4" -> "samjs/bazz:1.4.4"
    "samjs/bar:1.3.4" -> "samjs/p:1.3.5"
    "samjs/bar:1.3.4" -> "samjs/q:1.4.4"
    "samjs/bazz:1.4.4" -> "samjs/b:1.3.4"
    "samjs/bazz:1.4.4" -> "samjs/c:0.4.6"
    "samjs/c:0.4.6" -> "samjs/t:4.6.1"
    "samjs/p:1.3.5" -> "samjs/t:4.6.1"
}
```